# cypress intercept - how can I force the server to ignore 404 after authentication middleware check for unexist url

Tags: authentication, http-status-code-404, cypress, middleware, intercept

I have trouble using `cy.intercept` testing API that not actually exist (after mocking data)
what I mean?
I have url like: .../users/**hello**.

```
cy.intercept("POST", "/users/hello", { fixture: "test.json" }).as(
  "getTestUser"
);
```

**hello** value (in the url) came from mock data (from previous response) which means that it is not actually exist in the DB / server does not know this value.
the final result: I am getting 404 from the server (it not really know this value and throw authentication error )
how can I resolve it? can I intercept a dummy url and set the server side to ignore this url and then return my stub?
tnx

Answer (score 0):

Your intercept is stubbing because you have specified a fixture. The request will never go to the server.

Take a look at the routes at the top of the test

[image]

When you specify a fixture, you will not get 404 from the server. The request will never get to the server (assuming you have specified the URL correctly on the intercept).

If you ***are*** getting a response from the server, it means the URL in the intercept is not matching correctly.

Take a look at the dev console network tab, check the full URL you are trying to catch.

Perhaps you just need a wildcard in front,

```js
cy.intercept("POST", "**/users/hello", { fixture: "test.json" })
  .as("getTestUser")
```